# ClientResponse object has no attribute 'status_code'

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, aiohttp, opentsdb

I am trying to push data to OpenTSDB using asyncio and aiohttp. I am getting the error **AttributeError: 'ClientResponse' object has no attribute 'status_code'**

My environment details:

- Python: 3.8
- aiohttp: 3.8.1

My Code:

```
    async def get_session(self):
        if not self.session:
            self.session = aiohttp.ClientSession()
        return self.session

    async def push(self, metrics):
        json_data = self.build_json_data(metrics)
        if not json_data:
            return

        sess = await self.get_session()
        r = await sess.post(self.url, data=json_data)
        LOGGER.debug("result code: %s", r.status_code)
```

What i am doing wrong? Any pointers to resolve this issue.

Comment: Found after a 30 second look at the docs - the attribute is named `status` not `status_code` https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_reference.html#aiohttp.ClientResponse.status

Comment: I am extremely sorry. I used my requests based logger statement in aiohttp also. I should have paid some attention. Thanks a lot for pointing my mistake

Comment: @Iain Shelvington comment is the answer.